# how to declare static NSString?

Tags: iphone

how to declare static NSString ,if i declare within the interface
as static NSString *str; and i set to property as
@property (nonatomic, retain) static NSString *sportsName;

it gives error?any tutorial

Answer (score 4):

If by static you mean it operates on the class and not the instance of the class, you do it like this:

```
//In the header file:
+ (NSString *)myStaticString;

//In the implementation file:
+ (NSString *)myStaticString { return @"Hello world!"; }
```

If by static you mean global, then just declare it outside the scope of a class.

`@property` declarations are only for instance (non-class) methods.  They cannot be used to declare accessors for a static variable.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way:

```
NSString *const someString = @"TheStringHere";
```

Answer (score 1):

This'll do it ;-)

```
- (void)foo {
    static NSString *bar = @"My String";
}
```